# MongoDB defining custom user metadata gives EJSON.parse('{"$undefined":true}') error

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to build the User Creation Function for my MongoDB database in App Services. The function itself is called when a user is registered. A user in my database has the following schema:

```
{
  "title": "UserSchema",
  "properties": {
    "_id": {
      "bsonType": "objectId"
    },
    "user_id": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    },
    "username": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    },
    "email": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    },
    "password": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    },
    "profilePic": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    },
    "createdAt": {
      "bsonType": "date"
    },
    "followers": {
      "bsonType": "array",
      "items": {
        "bsonType": "string"
      }
    },
    "following": {
      "bsonType": "array",
      "items": {
        "bsonType": "string"
      }
    },
    "cardsInCollection": {
      "bsonType": "array",
      "items": {
        "bsonType": "string"
      }
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "_id",
    "user_id",
    "username",
    "email",
    "password",
    "profilePic",
    "createdAt"
  ]
}
```

I tried coding the following function, the same as the docs say [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/app-services/users/custom-metadata/#std-label-user-creation-function).

```
exports = async function onUserCreation(user) {
  const customUserDataCollection = context.services
    .get("service") // here i have my service placed correctly
    .db("app") // i have my app put correctly
    .collection("users"); 
  try {
    await customUserDataCollection.insertOne({
      user_id: user.id,
      username:user.username,
      email: user.email,
      password: user.password,
      profilePic: user.profilePic,
      createdAt: user.createdAt,
      followers: user.following,
      following: user.followers,
      cardsInCollection: user.cardsInCollection,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(`Failed to create custom user data document for user:${user.id}`);
    throw e
  }
}
```

In the testing console, I tried the following input:

```
exports({
  id: "1234567890abcdef12345678",
  username: "someusername",
  email: "someemail@email",
  password: "password",
  profilePic: "yes",
  createdAt: Date.parse("2023-07-28T22:38:14.415+00:00"),
  followers: [],
  following: [],
  cardsInCollection: [],
})
```

but the result is as follows:

```
> took 148.904629ms
> result: 
{
  "$undefined": true
}
> result (JavaScript): 
EJSON.parse('{"$undefined":true}')
```

Am I doing something wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: Was the user inserted? The function doesn't look  o me like it's configured to return anything therefore I'm not sure the empty results is a bad thing? In fact perhaps it's a good thing as the error wasn't printed instead?

Comment: @user20042973 the user was not inserted

Comment: ` id: "1234567890abcdef12345678"` doesn't look like an ObjectId, perhaps cast it when a string is passed in? I'm not clear on how app services responds when an error is thrown, maybe check the logs on the service side?